# Why not usual topology in measure theory ?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Measure theory was introduced in the early 1900s by Lebesgue, at the same time with Hausdorff introducing the usual concept of topology, and publishing it in his book just before World War I. Measure theory is full with convergence and limit properties of measures, functions and integrals. Yet none of them uses usual toplogy. Is there a well thought out reply to why such a thing happens ?

Comment: I would strongly dispute the penultimate sentence. The probabilists' usual notion of convergence of probability measures *is* a topological notion. Also, what is "usual topology" meant to be?

Comment: Can you expand in what do you mean by "uses usual topology"?


Comment: Are you asking about why sigma algebras look kind of like topologies? Or if integrals with respect to a measure over a space depend on a topology of the space? 

Comment: I guess the meaning is: most convergence notions in measure theory (e.g. almost everywhere convergence) are not in any obvious way convergence of a sequence in a topological space.

Comment: Certainly, topological type processes are all the time used in measure theory. However, they never ever define a topology based on open, or alternatively, closed sets. That is, they never ever define a Hausdorff-Kuratowski-Bourbaki topology, which is the usual topology used by topologists. For instance, even in such sophisticated cases like the Schwartz distribution spaces, the respective usual topologies are clearly defined before being used.

Comment: I propose that the OP makes his question more precise.

Comment: @ron l winger: I still don't understand. Strong convergence of measures is given by a metric. With the metric you have the open sets.
Or a weak convergence by a weak topology. Or is it saying that that convergence it not usually introduced by giving the topology but defining the convergence directly instead?

Comment: See Lorant Schwartz's "Analysis".

Comment: Well, let us take one of the most important theorems, namely, the Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem for integrals. Where is the HKB, or in other words, usual topology which has as convergent sequences precisely those in that theorem, and none less, and none more ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the OP is asking. At this point I'd say it's not a real question. "Usual topology?" I don't know probability theory, but the measure theory I do know, which is basically Radon measures on locally compact Hausdorff spaces is visibly linked essentially with the topology of the underlying space. In particular, Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is designed to interact nicely with the "usual topology" of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (as is Haar measure on any locally compact group).

Comment: @ron l winger: The topology will be related to a notion of convergence not to a criterion of convergence such as dominated convergence. What convergence in what set are you considering?

Comment: Before instant voting, how about some calm thinking ? The issue is simple : most of the convergent sequences used in measure theory do NOT correspond to a Hausdorff-Kuratowsky-Bourbaki, that is, usual topology. Any such usual topology would have either many more convergent sequences, of quite a lot fewer. And then the question is : Is there some other concept of topology appropriate instances of which may MATCH various sets of convergent sequences in measure theory ? Kelly in his famous 1950s book on topology lists four criteria for such a match but only in the case of usual topologies.

Comment: It is possible to give an equivalent definition of topology as a rule determining which nets (a generalization of sequences) converge to what. See Willard's book General Topology for details. However, one of the axioms is rather ugly-looking. I assume that in the analytic cases you discuss, either these axioms do not hold, or they are not useful enough, in the opinion of most expositors, to warrant discussion.

Comment: @Charles I think there's an MO question on this very topic i.e. alternate axiomatization of topological spaces via nets. 

Comment: While I think there's the germ of an interesting question here, I don't think the question as posed is sufficiently well-defined. Words like "most" and "usual" don't help - *specific* examples, with s*specific* statements, would be much easier for other to interpret and respond to. Voting to close.

Comment: It is one thing "what one thinks", and it is quite another "what really is". And for any scientist the priority is on "what really is", to which priority one has to adapt "what one thinks". The question is real, regardless "what one happens to think". It did bother me for many years. And I am far from being an amateur or novice in mathematics. For details, please, see my comment below to Oleg Reinov ...

Comment: Elemer, you seem to have misunderstood me. I was asking "ron l winger" to try and formulate the question more precisely, along the lines you and others have suggested. If he or she does not want to do that, then I can only apologize for the under-development of my telepathic skills.

Comment: In any case, I don't quite follow why one should feel compelled to fit convergence a.e. in Procrustean fashion into what you and ron l winger call "usual topology". It is what it really is, to use your own phrase. Just as weak convergence of probability measures, a fairly standard and possibly important part of the theory *is* a functional-analytic notion and is precisely the convergence of a sequence in a certain weak topology.

Answer (score 3):

It is true that convergence a.e. is not the convergence of a topology.  If you want a topology you can go to convergence in measure.  A theorem MORE GENERAL THAN the dominated convergence theorem: let $f_n \to f$ in measure on a set $E$ of finite measure, and suppose there is an integrable $g$ with $|f_n| \le g$ a.e.  Then $\int_E f_n \to \int_E f$.  SPECIAL CASE: $f_n \to f$ a.e.